# I am making ASP.Net MVC2 Web Service not WCF. How do I easily create WSDL for it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

If I use WCF getting a WSDL response or file is a piece of cake.

I'm not.., I am using MVC2 to create my web service that will serialize eventually XML and Json.

Schema definition aside.., I want to easily have my ASP.Net MVC2 Web Service have a service definition defining the methods, types, parameters, and etc.  Hopefully you get the picture.

Am I missing something in VS 2010 that does this, a codeplex project, or whatever.
Is it that I have to build a WSDL pro-grammatically from scratch?

Please help.

Comment: If you're doing a "ASP.NET MVC" webservice then this is usually a REST-oriented service - not a SOAP service. REST doesn't have anything like WSDL.....

Comment: If REST doesn't have anything like WSDL then with REST-oriented service how do you explain to the calling or consumer of the service how to use the web service?

Comment: by following [RESTful conventions](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SimplyRestfulRouting) and especially by writing a good documentation. Here's one example of [good documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/reference.html).

Comment: Darin nailed it on the head - one of the **BIG** drawbacks of REST in my opinion is the lack of a facility like WSDL. You as a consumer of a REST service are at the mercy of the producer providing a good, comprehensive, and understandable **documentation** - something a lot of folks don't really do well....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a WSDL then use WCF as it already has this functionality built-in and don't reinvent wheels. If you go the ASP.NET MVC way of generating JSON and XML you are pretty much on your own. And don't forget that WSDL is a SOAP artifact and not JSON or XML.

If you decide to go the REST route, make sure you follow the well [established conventions](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SimplyRestfulRouting) 
and write a good documentation for your service consumers.